# Method for calculating the expected value of a ratio of two random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, expected-value

I have a random variable:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A} = \frac{cos(2\pi\theta)}{\alpha} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $\theta \sim U(0,1)$, $\alpha \sim (-1)^{X} \cdot U(0.1,10)$ and $P(X=0)=0.5 \land P(X=1)=0.5$

From this it follows that $\mathbb{E}[cos(2\pi\theta)]=\mathbb{E}[\alpha]=0$ but I am not sure how to calculate:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{A}] \tag{2}
\end{equation}

If I do the calculation I obtain an indeterminate form i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{A}]= \frac{0}{0}$ but my intuition tells me that the actual value might be 1. Might there be a rigorous method for settling this matter?

**Note:** I now realise that my misconception was that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{\alpha}]=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[\alpha]}=\frac{1}{\infty}$.

Comment: Does this notation mean that $\alpha$ is uniform in $[-100,-1]\cup[1,100]$ ?

Comment: Mind that the expectation of the ratio is *not* the ratio of the expectations !

Comment: I fixed a typo in the question. alpha is uniform in $[-10,0.1] \cup  [0.1,10]$.

Comment: By symmetry, the probabilities of the positive and negative values are equal, hence zero expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate $E [1/\alpha]$, not $E[\alpha]$. Assuming, of course, that $\theta$ and $\alpha$ are independent.  Under this assumption, the random variables $X=\cos(2\pi\theta)$ and $Y=1/\alpha$ are also independent.

In general  the expectation of the product, $E[XY]$, of independent random variables is given by the product of their expectstions: $$E[XY] =E[X]E[Y].$$ In your case,  you have $$E\mathcal A =E[\cos(2\pi\theta)(1/\alpha)]=  E[\cos (2\pi \theta)] E[1/\alpha].$$

Comment: These two random variables are independent but I’m not sure how calculating 1/alpha simplifies anything.

Comment: I have tried to address your uncertainty in an edit to my answer.  I think you should reread the chapter in your textbook.

Comment: Actually, everything you have said so far was clear to me. The challenge is that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{\alpha}]=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[\alpha]}=\frac{1}{\infty}$

Comment: @AidanRocke: next misconception: $\mathbb E(1/x)\ne1/\mathbb E(x)$ !

Comment: Ok. So if I understand correctly we should apply the law of the unconscious statistician and we get zero expectation.